# Django -editing files in bash

Tags: django, bash, command-line

I just installed Django on my Mac and I am trying to figure out a way to edit the python modules directly from the terminal.

I know I can view the contents of a file using the less command in the command line, but is there a way I can edit Django modules from the command line, as well? It's just kind of annoying having to switch between the command line and a text editor, so I was hoping I could do everything in one spot.

Thanks,

Jerry

EDIT: rephrased.

Comment: what do you mean by "switch between bash and python"? You can run any command from Bash, any editor you like, but Bash is not a text editor, you should use some other program to edit source code files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots of TUI text editors available for *nix. vim and emacs are popular, and are available in several forms for OS X.

Answer (score 1):

This question is a little confused.

There's no such thing as "editing in Python", or "editing in Bash". I don't know what you're regarding as the "Python" that you have to switch to, but most people using a Mac edit their Python files in something like Textmate. That can be always running, and the Django development server automatically reloads when you save changes to any of the files in use, so this is the often most convenient way of doing it.

Bash is the shell that runs inside the terminal. Instead of talking about "editing in Bash", I expect you mean "editing in the terminal". Of course, there are hundreds of editors that run inside the terminal. One that comes installed on the Mac is `vim`, which I use all the time - but it has its fair share of idiosyncrasies, and takes a lot of getting used to.

However, if anything, editing in vim inside the terminal seems like it would involve *more* "switching" rather than less. You'd either need to have a separate terminal tab, and switch between the one running the server and the one running vim, or continually quit your server to go into vim.